# Why does not any message appear on console (console.log() in QtQuick apps)

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to display messages on command prompt, 
when I run a QtQuick application from command prompt.

Here is my source code for trial.

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
   title: qsTr("Console test")
   width: 640
   height: 480

   menuBar: MenuBar {
       Menu {
           title: qsTr("File")
           MenuItem {
               text: qsTr("Exit")
               onTriggered:{
                   Qt.quit();
               }
           }
           MenuItem {
               text: qsTr("Start")
               onTriggered: console.log("start button is pressed.")
           }
       }
   }

   Button {
       text: qsTr("Hello World")
       anchors.centerIn: parent
   }
```

}

In QtCreator IDE, it works as expected.
(the message was displayed on the console of IDE when I clicked munu item "start".)

In command prompt, however, No message is displayed.
Does anyone know why?

Although I read [this article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-debugging.html), I have no idea how to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

[ Configurations ]

OS: Windows 8.1(32bit)
Kits: Desktop Qt 5.2.0 MSVC2012 32bit
IDE: QtCreator 3.0

Comment: Missing `CONFIG += console` in your .pro file?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.Now it works as expected by adding the line "CONFIG += console" in .pro file. To　tell　the truth, I've done it before I asked this question.But it didn't work until I deleted Debug folder which was generated automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since @peppe has not written any answer yet after his comment, I am now stealing all the glories from him!

You need to use `CONFIG += console`. As you seem to have figured out, it is better to start with a clean directory in trouble, just in case.